# On the issue of solidifying the ckpt model in TensorFlow into a pb model

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, computer-vision

I recently reproduced a paper on SRNet that uses the TensorFlow1. X framework, while I am using TensorFlow2.0. After completing the model training, there were problems encountered during the phase of converting CKPT to PB:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bxkVz.png)
And this problem has been stuck with me for three full days. Can you help me analyze and solve this problem? I am a novice.

My CKPT_ To_PB.py is as follows：

```
from tensorflow.python.framework import graph_util
tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()

# output_node_names 为输出节点的名字
def freeze_graph(path='/home/ps/thy_projects/Steganalysis-StegoRemoval-main/0.Model/Model_500000.ckpt',
                 output='/home/ps/thy_projects/Steganalysis-StegoRemoval-main/0.Model/output_model/pb_model/frozen_model.pb'):
    tf.reset_default_graph()  # 清除默认图
    saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph(path + '.meta')
    graph = tf.get_default_graph()
    input_graph_def = graph.as_graph_def()

    with tf.Session() as sess:
        # 不需要初始化 batch_size，因为它是一个占位符

        # 加载模型检查点
        saver.restore(sess, path)

        output_node_names = ['ip/BiasAdd']  # 请确保这个名称与你的模型输出节点的名称匹配
        print(output_node_names)
        output_graph_def = graph_util.convert_variables_to_constants(
            sess=sess,
            input_graph_def=input_graph_def,
            output_node_names=output_node_names
        )

        with tf.gfile.GFile(output, 'wb') as fgraph:
            fgraph.write(output_graph_def.SerializeToString())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    freeze_graph()
```

I have been checking for three days and still don't know where the problem is